# Hive metastore partition , how it works?

Tags: hive, partition, metastore

I have couple of query , please help me to understand

1. In Hive I see for couple of hive tables , Partitions information in cluster  and in metastore are different what could be the reason ?

used   "hive> show partitions " in Hive  and " SELECT * FROM PARTITIONS  WHERE TBL_ID=;"  in metastore.

2. For some hive tables I see less number of partition information in Cluster but in metastore it is showing more partition . For this type of case when running query in hive tables using where clause for partition it is giving error that some partition are missing .

Where as there are some hive tables for which metastore has less number of partition information compare to cluster and in that case query is not giving error when running query using partition in where clause .

Answer (score 1):

I suppose you are using Cloudera/Impala. The documentation says: If you believe an object exists but you cannot see it in the SHOW output, check with the system administrator if you need to be granted a new privilege for that object.
A table could span multiple different HDFS directories if it is partitioned. The directories could be widely scattered because a partition can reside in an arbitrary HDFS directory based on its LOCATION attribute.

See here: [show partitions](https://www.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/5-8-x/topics/impala_show.html#show_partitions)